# If statment in Azure Devops Yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I can't figure out how to make this if statment works:

```
- pwsh: |
    $affected = 'bleh'
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=affected;isOutput=true]$affected"
- ${{ if eq(variables.affected.Contains('bleh'), 'True') }}:
    [...]
```

It says `Unexpected symbol (`, which is the `(` in `eq(`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your syntax.

Firstly you are using template syntax to read the variable that in your pipeline is not set before compile. The template syntax (the expressions wrapped with {{) are evaluated at compile time, before your variable is set (during runtime). For more info on variable syntax see here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables#understand-variable-syntax Instead of using an inline template, you could use a condition attribute for your second step. Condition syntax > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions

Secondly you are setting isOutput to true, this is used for passing variables between jobs. It sets the variable is a different place than if you dont have the isOutput option set. For more info on setting variables during runtime see here > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables#set-variables-in-scripts

Thirdly to do a contains check the syntax is contains(string, sub-string), not string.contains(sub-string). See > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions#contains

If you want to conditionally run the second step based on the variable set by the first, try this:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
  $affected = 'bleh'
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=affected]$affected"
- pwsh: echo "do something"
  condition: contains(variables.affected, 'bleh')
```